# What is the Id Item for the button with a return arrow in Activity with menu?

Tags: android, menuitem

I have an activity in Android Studio with menu:

```js
@Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
```

The menu has a button with the image of an arrow to return to the previous activity:

The event that occurs with the menu buttons is as follows:

```js
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        }
}
```

My question is:

What value does item.getItemId() have when the button mentioned is pressed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the id

```
case android.R.id.home:
    //Your code
break;
```